# flask using POST, PUT, DELETE

Tags: python, post, sql-delete, put, flash-message

I keep getting an error on the url when I try to implement POST in my API. I keep getting the error in the URL saying METHOD not Allowed for this URL. Am I missing something? Does POST not work directly when u try to open the server?? I'm soooo lost.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify,json, request, abort
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('Config.py')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.create_all()

class JsonModel(object):
    def as_dict(self):
         return {c.name: getattr(self, c.name) for c in self.__table__.columns}

class User(db.Model, JsonModel):
    User_ID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    FirstName = db.Column(db.String(20))
    LastName = db.Column(db.String(20))

    def __init__(self,FirstName, LastName):
         self.FirstName = FirstName
         self.LastName = LastName

class Todo(db.Model, JsonModel):
    todo_ID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    UserID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('User_ID'))
    details = db.Column(db.String(30))

    def __init__(self,details):
        self.details = details

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def index():
    return json.dumps([u.as_dict() for u in User.query.all()+Todo.query.all()])

@app.route('/todo/<int:UserID>', methods = ['GET'])
def get(UserID):
    return (list[Todo.query.get(UserID)])

@app.route('/p/', methods = ['POST'])
def create_dev():
    if not request.json or not 'name' in request.json:
    abort(400)
    dev = Todo(request.json.details,request.json.get('details',''))
    db.session.add(dev)
    db.session.commit()
    return json.dumps([{'dev': dev}]), 201

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: On which URL do You get this error?

Comment: It's the /p/ one which has to do with POST

Comment: Does it say which method is not allowed? My guess is that You try to load page by visiting http://some.address/p and app is complaining because You don't have GET method covered here.

Comment: uh i kinda get what you mean but then that means that the first thing opened is the GET method, how do i change it to post then o.o. Do i have to test POST some other way ?

Answer (score 2):

You should add GET method to list of allowed methods. When You try to load page, You first need to get page itself using GET method. Then, after filling something on the page, You use POST method to pass some data to the app. In the app, You should check with which method function is called. Something like this:

```
@app.route('/p', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def create_dev():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('p_page.html')

    # If You get to this line, it means it is POST method
    do_something_here()
```

Comment: What do u mean by filling something in the page? I can't add anything into the browser.

Comment: What data are You sending to the app? I suppose You have some entry field, radio button, drop-down list?

Comment: I'm not makign an app. Just a basic API that gets, puts, udpates and deletes stuff from a database

Comment: You mean, You're sending POST request with some data using, say, curl?

Comment: I want to but I'm not sure how

Comment: One way is to use something like this: `curl -X POST -d @filename.txt http://example.com/path/to/resource --header "Content-Type:application/json"`. If You do use this sort of testing, You do not need to specify GET in methods.

Comment: umm what goes inside the txt file? im not sure what file i'm suposed to put.